# what are my name servers and search domains?

Tags: networking, server, system-installation, software-installation, dns

Doing a fresh ubuntu 20.04 server install but want to have static ip, what should i put in for name servers and search domains?

Everything should be handled by my router usually.
Do i put in my routers ip address for these name servers? And perhaps include 8.8.8.8 aswell?

With my name server out the way i need to know my search domain. Is that also my routers ip? Or is it localhost?

Im kind of lost and his is something i should definetly know, ubuntu guide doesnt help, and Google isnt helpfull either with most results i find with it talk about .com server installations for search domains...

Comment: If you usually let your router handle things, then why not continue using DHCP, and assign a fixed IP for your server's MAC address in the router?

Comment: Ok but what are my search domain and name server supposed to be? I wish to have it setup on Linux , this is my 2nd time installing as i dodnt setup in installation before, changed to static ip after booting whilst following a guide and then managed to not be able to fetch updates, an issue with resolving ubuntu archives ...

Comment: I used my router IP and set search domains blank in the end, seems to work...

Comment: To solve this i had to go into windows , do a ipconfig /all